# how to add menu items

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

Like the older version of android studio menu is not pre generated. So I tried and added some code of my own. But unfortunately I am unable to add menu items. So need some help:(

MainActivity:

```
package com.buckydroid.materialapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
      android:title="next"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
      app:showAsAction="always"
      />
</menu>
```

app_bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    android:titleTextColor="#fff"


    >

</Toolbar>
```

So if you need any other codes then comment :(

Comment: Can u share the main activity xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code in MainActivity.java

from

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

To

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I hope it will fix the problem...

Comment: Still I am facing the problem :(

Comment: oh let me see again